# Controlling mouse movement with python inside a game

Tags: python

I want to learn some reinforcement-learning concepts by letting my agent play a video game. In order to do so, I would like to control the mouse movement inside the game.

I've been fiddling with **win32api**, using `win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))`to move the mouse. While this works perfectly on my desktop, I can't find a way to translate the movement inside the game.

I have also tried using **pyautogui** with no luck either.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button


def clickAt(Mouse, x, y):
    Mouse.position = (x, y)
    Mouse.press(Button.right)
    Mouse.release(Button.right)


Mouse = Controller()
clickAt(Mouse,100,100)
```

This is how you do it with pynput

Comment: same problem as with the other modules I've tried. It works on desktop but not ingame :S

Comment: Put the game in windowed mode rather than full screen.

Comment: I did, but once I click on the game window the mouse "disappears". It recognizes mouse clicks but not the movement

Comment: That's a different question all together, you need to figure out what library/how the game itself is handling input and then find a way to simulate so that it behaves as you want.